# How to select the text inside quotes in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, selection, quotes, shortcut

i want to select the text that is inside of quotes in Eclipse.

> For example: "This is a String"

How can i select what is inside the quotes?
The Solution has to be that I only select the text inside quotes without the quotes.

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut or a template.

Google search yielded no results for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Put the caret just after `"` wherever in the Java code. Then, double click mouse button. This will automatically select all text up-to next matching character (excluding itself).

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy.

For example:

```
String mes = "Hello world"; //Copies Hello world

String mes1 = "Hello \"John\"" // Copies Hello \"John\" to clipboard without outer double quotes
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats not exactly what i was looking for but you gave me the idea to solve it myself.

Comment: I tried to solve it with autohotkey to automate a double click but i cant get the corret coordinates from eclipse about where the caret is.

Comment: By default eclipse won't provide such shortcut key. You have to write you own plugin to do it. Ask separate question to get the character position in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

For me "Alt" + "Shift" + "arrow up" works when the cursor is inside the quoted string. Note that the selection includes the quotes. Instead of "arrow up" you can also use "arrow left" or "right".

You can find and change this behavior under Windows->Preferences->General->Keys

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am looking for a way to select the text without the quotes specifically.